# Regex for matching multi-line PHPDoc comments

Tags: php, regex, find, phpstorm, phpdoc

```
/**
 * Get Data
 *
 * @param null|ProductInterface $product
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
```

I would like to find PHPDoc multi-lines using the regex, such that there isn't an empty line between the PHPDoc @ elements of different types. For example, as between

> ** @return string 
> ** @throws LocalizedException

as opposed to:

> ** @param null|ProductInterface $product 
> **  
> ** @return string

If you're wondered why I need that - I have to add a new empty line between PHPDoc @ elements of different types (@param and @throws in that case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work:

**Regex:**

```
^ \* @([a-z]+).*\K(?=\r?\n^ \* @(?!\1))
```

- `^ \* @([a-z]+).*` - capture a PHPDoc line and put whatever is after the `@` into capture group `\1`
- `\K` - forget everything we just captured but `\1` will remain available

  - `\K` is specific to PCRE
  - In the replacement I don't want to deal with capture groups so my goal is to assert my position where I want to add the new line
- `(?=\r?\n^ \* @(?!\1))` - ahead of me should be another PHPDoc line and the text after `@` is not allowed to be the same as what is stored in `\1`

**Replacement:**

```
\n *
```

https://regex101.com/r/nZpgkF/1

^ I modified the test string to have multiple things to split so that you can see how it works.

---

If `\K` is not available in your regex flavor:

**Regex**

```
(^ \* @([a-z]+).*)(?=\r?\n^ \* @(?!\2))
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1\n *
```

https://regex101.com/r/DZ5EKw/1